# Instantly hide the message when the value of input field is changed

Tags: angular

If the form is submitted and it checks if emailExists the response comes from the backend as true or false.
 It correctly prints if the email already exists but the message stays there. I want that the message should disappear if the user changes the value of the email field.

```
<input type="text" formControlName="email" name="email" placeholder="Email *"/>
 <div *ngIf="submitted>
 <div *ngIf="emailExists">This email has already been registered</div>
 </div>
```

I added this in the input field

```
<input (change)="cccx()"
```

In ts file

```
 cccx() {
  this.emailExists = false;
  }
```

This hides the error message but only when the user leaves the email and clicks somewhere else and not instantly when the value is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the different event in that case.

```
<input (keyup)="cccx()"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind msg div with your from field like:

```
<div *ngIf="email.invalid">
```

now on change of input value you can set validation of input field dynamically using [setValidators()](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValidators) function